# Find out which slaves are using a deprecated agent protocol in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to find out which slaves of a given Jenkins Master is connecting with anything other than *JNLP4* programmatically.

There is already an [*AdministrativeMonitor* for checking whether deprecated protocols are activated](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/393680beb5d64628bdf8d9e5bf8daf4cab2191ad/core/src/main/java/jenkins/slaves/DeprecatedAgentProtocolMonitor.java), unfortunately this does not tell me which slaves are actually using it. The deprecation itself is done using a boolean flag that is baked into the source, see e.g. here for [JNLP2](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/efdd52e9e78cc057ea49a7d338ee575d131c1959/core/src/main/java/jenkins/slaves/JnlpSlaveAgentProtocol2.java).

What have I tried? Digging through the Jenkins source code on GitHub directly to find out a connection between a `hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer` and the protocol itself. There is a `Channel` abstraction in between, which is the point at which I've currently stopped my investigations.

Starting from the following code (written using Groovy in Scriptler), what are the steps to find out the agent protocol?

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
Jenkins.instance.computers.each() { c ->
    if(c instanceof hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer) {
        // <Find out agent protocol of c>
    };
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your subject.

Comment: Could you please be more precise as to what you are objecting? I've started the question with an interrogative, and it summarizes what problem I'm trying to solve.